# Undo text entry in Jupyter Notebook under Win7

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I was surprised I did not find an answer to this question on Jupyter Notebook under Win7 here or on the web.

I just overwrote by mistake a larger part of a call block, but not all. Autosave dates back some previous changes that I do not want to revert. Where is the undo function for text entries in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: If you click inside the cell you edited, pressing Ctrl-Z should undo the changes.

Answer (score 9):

Hit the `ESC` key to enter Command Mode.  Now you can hit the `h` key to see all available commands.  To undo an entry you have to go back to Edit Mode (hit `ENTER`) and then do a `CTRL-Z`.