# How to undo a command in jupyter notebook after execution a No. of command?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

1. How i can undo a command in jupyter notebook, let suppose in the provided code i treated outliers in my `data['age']` column by replacing them by a value 72 for all the outliers which lies beyond 72 (as shown in the below code). But after few more finding i thought it would be appropriate if i replace values which is beyond 75 not 72 in 'age' column. how can i retrieve my data back as i have already ran few more commands after this line?
2. if accidentally i deleted a column in my data and saved it as in the same variable data(as shown in below code for column 'customer ID'), then how can i get it back? as i have already ran many commands after deleting the column.

```
#1
data[(data['age']>72)]==72
```

```
#2
data=data.drop(columns='customer ID',axis=1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161496/undo-text-entry-in-jupyter-notebook-under-win7

Answer (score 5):

You simply can't.
If you overwrite your variable then there is no way to go to a previous state unless you reload your data, run your script up to the point you wish to modify and then run a different command.

In your two examples, you will have to reload `data`.

Answer (score 0):

A very good question, but it seems there isn't anyway to undo an executed command since the machine has already learned the command which you mistakenly executed.

```
 Wished if there was a way like erasing the events in memory, as in the move men in black!!

 The only way around for now is to reload the data back to machine, making it learning the data again.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).